# PowerConnect 2808 and syslog

Tags: switch, cli, dell, powerconnect, syslog

I have a pair of Dell PowerConnect 2808 managed switches. I am attempting to enable syslog on them, but not having any luck.

I have searched the web interface, used telnet to log into the CLI interface, and cannot find the syslog functionality. I know that it is keeping a log (I assume in flash) because when I enter (from the CLI) "show tech-support config" I can see section being reported that looks like this:

```
------------------ show logging ------------------
Logging is enabled.
Console Logging: Level info. Console Messages: 0 Dropped.
Buffer Logging: Level info. Buffer Messages: 20 Logged, 20 Displayed, 20 Max.
File Logging: Level error. File Messages: 0 Logged, 35 Dropped.
2 messages were not logged

Application filtering control
Application                 Event                       Status
--------------------        --------------------        ---------
AAA                         Login                       Enabled
File system                 Copy                        Enabled

01-Jan-2000 00:02:24 :%INIT-I-Startup: Warm Startup
(...other log entries follow...)
```

I have tried the following commands, but no luck:

```
console# show logging
% Unrecognized command
console# show logging file
% Unrecognized command
console# show syslog
% Unrecognized command
console# show syslog-servers
% Unrecognized command
```

The firmware on them is current, and they are vanilla, right out of the box, so nothing "weird" has been done to them. I would just like them to report the same way that their big brothers do.

Is there a secret or alternate way to enable this basic functionality in these switches?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What part of that output suggests it does syslog? (hint: it doesn't)

Comment: The "01-Jan-2000 00:02:24 :%INIT-I-Startup: Warm Startup" line and the other log entries.
Additionally, the documentation suggests that it does, and that it runs a similar version of the CLI than other PowerConnect series switches do.

Comment: There is no mention at all of syslog in the 2800 series user manual. *Console*, *Buffer*, and *File*, but no mention of any "host" logging. [http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/powerconnect-2808_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf]

Comment: Your link is 404, but I have the documentation in hand.  I was referencing an advertising slick that purported that it did, in fact, support syslog.  I cannot find it referenced in the documentation.  This is very silly not to include such basic functionality in any "managed" switch.  I know it's only a little 8 port unit, but it supports DHCP, SNMP, and QoS like its big brothers.  Why no syslog is beyond me.  Guess I will change the logging level to the console and leave a telnet session open to it in order to catch any events.

Comment: Take the trailing `]` off

Comment: Sneaky.  Didn't see it hiding way over on the end there... thanks